# How to set constructor initialize list with derive class template that contains different typedef enum?

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance

I have a `class template` `Piece`

```
template <typename T>
class Piece
{
public:
    Piece()
    : m_texture(TextureMap::TileTextureID::CITY1) // ERROR!!!! See question bellow
    {
    }

    //...
private:
    Texture<T>              m_texture;
};
```

Also, I have the classes `Tile` and `Meeple` (not templates, but both derived from the `class template` `Piece` (each one, with a different texture):

```
class Tile : public Piece<TextureMap::TileTextureID>
{
public:
    Tile();
    ~Tile();
    //...
};

class Meeple: public Piece<TextureMap::MeepleTextureID>
{
public:
    Meeple();
    ~Meeple();
    //...
};
```

Finally, I have a class `TextureMap`:

```
class TextureMap
{
public:
    TextureMap();
    ~TextureMap();

    typedef enum
    {
        CITY1,
        CITY2,
    } TileTextureID;

    typedef enum
    {
        RED,
        BLUE
    } MeepleTextureID;

};
```

**The question:**

As you can see, I need to initialize the `m_texture` in the initialize list on the `Piece` constructor...
And I want to initialize it this way:

- If the `Piece` is instantiated as `Piece<TileTextureID>`, then I want the constructor initialize list to be:

  m_texture(TextureMap::TileTextureID::CITY1)
- But if the `Piece` is instantiated as `Piece<MeepleTextureID>`, I want to be:

  m_texture(TextureMap::MeepleTextureID::RED)

**How can I do this in the class template Piece?**

**The ERROR:**

```
error C2664: 'Texture<T>::Texture(T)' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'TextureMap::TileTextureID' to 'TextureMap::MeepleTextureID'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use template specialization.

First you leave the base function undefined. Optionally you can define it with a default code.

```
template <typename T>
class Piece
{
public:
    Piece();
};
```

And then you specialize the constructor:

```
template<> Piece<TileTextureID>::Piece()
    :m_texture(TextureMap::TileTextureID::CITY1)
{
}
```

And similarly for the other specialization.

Note that if the unspecialized constructor is undefined you will not be able to instantiate if of arbitrary types. For example `Piece<int>` will fail with `Piece<int>::Piece()` undefined.

Alternatively, since your code is quite simple, you could use function overloading and avoid specialization. You need a dummy argument because you cannot overload by return type alone:

```
TileTextureID default_texture_value(TileTextureID *)
{ return TileTextureID::CITY1; }
MeepleTextureID default_texture_value(MeepleTextureID *)
{ return MeepleTextureID::RED; }
```

And now the constructor is easy:

```
template <typename T>
class Piece
{
public:
    Piece()
        :m_texture(default_texture_value((T*)NULL)
    {
    }
};
```

You can also mix the two ideas in what is sometimes called a *traits* type. It may be overkilling for your scenario, but it may be useful if you have many related varying functionality per enum:

```
template<typename T> struct texture_traits {};

template<> struct texture_traits<TileTextureID>
{
    static TileTextureID default_texture_value()
    { return TileTextureID::CITY1; }
};

template <typename T>
class Piece
{
public:
    Piece()
      :m_texture(texture_traits<T>::default_texture_value())
    {}
};
```

Or for even extra flexibility:

```
template <typename T, typename TT = texture_traits<T> >
class Piece
{
public:
    Piece()
      :m_texture(TT::default_texture_value())
    {}
};
```